# Disable Ctrl + spacebar MATE

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I have MATE on my Ubuntu computer but I have a little and simple problem. I play games in fullscreen and when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> it uncaptures the mouse. How can I disable this function of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Space</kbd> set to "next input method" (whatever that means) in my IBus Preferences. It said space, so I took all that out and left it an empty field. The IBus Preferences is also called "Input Method" or "Keyboard Input Methods" in the MATE Control Center menus.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System > Control Center and, in the filter bar, type 'Keyboard Shortcuts'. Click on the resulting configuration tool to open a new window listing all your keyboard shortcuts. Find the 'Ctrl+Space' shortcut, select it, and hit backspace. The shortcut will now be disabled.

Comment: I don't see it there. Maybe it's just a feature that's made into MATE or something? Does ti happen to you, or is it just me?

Comment: Nothing happens when I press Ctrl + Space. This is kind of a long-shot but... are you running Ubuntu MATE virtually by any chance? (using Virtualbox or some other program?)

Comment: Nope. Not virtual. When you said it didn't do anything, did you have your mouse captured in something like a game? If you don't have it captured, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I have found a solution! I am making it into an answer...

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste Great!